# Does a solution of pH zero contain hydroxide ions?

Tags: ph

Are there hydroxide ions in a solution of pH 0?

Comment: You mean p**H** 0? Yes, of course.

Comment: Yes, but very few.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. There are $10^{14}$ times as many $\ce{H+}$ as $\ce{OH-}$ in a solution of pH 0. From the formula $$K_w=\ce{[H+][OH-]}$$ you can see there will always be both $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{OH-}$ in an aqueous solution regardless of the pH.

Answer (score 1):

Yes -- assuming you mean an aqueous solution.

In an aqueous solution there are always *some* hydroxide ions present, but if the pH is very low, there will be very few. The relationship is:

$\ce{[H^+][OH^-] = 10^{-14}}$

At pH = 0, $\ce{[H+] = 10^{-0} = 1}$ (by definition of pH), so $\ce{[OH^-] = 10^{-14}}$

$10^{-14}$ M is very, very low concentration -- but not none.